# Crop a pdf File with selcted page number in scala

Tags: scala, pdfbox

I have a pdf file of 50 pages and I have to crop the selected pages of the pdf file and save it to another pdf file. I am using Scala Language. How can I do this?

The output of this should be only 4 pages in the new pdf file but it is saving all the remaining 46 pages with the 4 cropped file in the new pdf.

What am I doing wrong here?

My code is:  --

```
 var croppedPdf: PDDocument = null
  try {

    croppedPdf = PDDocument.load(pdf)    // pdf file with 50 Pages in it
    val pageno = pageNoList.asScala      // [2,4,6,8] these are the pages need to be croped

    pageno.foreach(page => {
      croppedPdf.getPage(page).setCropBox(new PDRectangle(166f, 470f, 262f, 355f))

    })

    println("saving pdf files")
    val outputFile = new File(outputFilePath)
    try (outputFile.createNewFile())
    croppedPdf.save(outputFile)
    Some(outputFile)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      println("Got exception while generate PdfFile file")
      e.printStackTrace()
      None
  } finally {
    try (croppedPdf.close())
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `PDDocument` from an existing file, changing a few pages, and then writing it out to a new file.

If you want to keep only the changed pages you either have to A) delete all the unchanged pages before writing it out, or B) create an empty `PDDocument` and add only the changed pages to it.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle
import java.io.{File,FileInputStream}

util.Using.Manager { use =>
  val inFile = use(new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/infile.pdf")))
  val inPdf  = use(PDDocument.load(inFile))  // pdf doc to read from
  val outPdf = use(new PDDocument())         // pdf doc to write to

  val pages = List(2,5)  //the pages to be cropped
  pages.foreach { pNum =>
    val page = inPdf.getPage(pNum)
    page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(166f, 470f, 262f, 355f))
    outPdf.addPage(page)
  }
  outPdf.save("path/to/outfile.pdf")
}
//res0: scala.util.Try[Unit] = Success(())
```

Note: This example uses the Scala 2.13 `Using.Manager` which automatically closes all resources that it opens.

Comment: My scala version is 2.13 but still Using.Manager is not working in it. Please suggest some alternative way

Comment: I have tried creating new empty PDDocument and add pages to it but it is giving the null pointer exception

Comment: @kislaykashyap; "not working" is not an adequate description of the problem you are facing. The posted code compiles, runs, and produces expected results. (At least the results _I_ expected.) I suggest you start with a small working example, more or less as posted, and then make small incremental mods to adapt it to your needs. As soon as something breaks, stop and fix it.